# Which one is correct? "Believe" word grammar

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

Which sentence is correct?

> He believed that brain **is linked** to emotion.
>
> He believed that brain **was linked** to emotion.

I think **"is linked"** is correct because he believes in a fact, am I right?

Comment: They can both be correct. It depends on the context that the sentence occurs in (or the situation which it describes). Therefore, to get a good answer to the question, it will probably be better if you explain to us why you are asking. (That probably means that you need to tell us the story of things that happened that made you ask the question, where you saw the sentence, etc.)

You are probably guessing that the simple present *is* is correct because grammars often say that we use it for "general truths" or "things that are always true". But the realities are not so simple as that.

Comment: As as an aside, it has to be *the* brain, because *brain* is a countable noun and you can't use it without an article.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Simple Present Tense for general truth in the past](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/149691/using-simple-present-tense-for-general-truth-in-the-past)

Comment: "He believed that brain" is not correct English here at all.

Answer (score 1):

Different options are possible.

> He believed that the brain is linked to emotion.

He believed in a sort of general statement of fact.  Such as "He believed that 'swans are white'."

> He believed that the brain was linked to emotion.

By using the past tense, it brings all the verbs into correspondence with each other, which can be a good thing.  "He believed that swans were white, that mice were small, and that the earth revolved around the sun."   It all matches in the past tense.